# Python Check if an integer is all the same digit

Tags: python

My goal here is to take a serial number and attempt to reject it. I need to reject anything that is not a number. I also need to reject anything where each digit is the same number. I know there has to be a way other than listing out 111111111 - 999999999. I need to mention that s is an integer with 9 digits such as 123456789. the set() method will not work here as an int object is not iterable.

```
def rejectSerial(s):
    try:
        int(s)
    except:
        return True
    rejectList = [111111111],[222222222],[333333333],[444444444],[555555555],[666666666]
    if s in rejectList:
        return True

    return False
```

Comment: `len(set(str(s))) < 2`?

Comment: A regular expression could possibly make it a oneliner.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?  Given the constraint that the input is a 9-digit integer, the list of rejects will be short enough to be practical.  I'd make it a set instead of a tuple though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the string to a set and see if it has more than 1 element in it:

```
return (len(set(s)) == 1)
```

The entire function could be:

```
def rejectSerial(s: str) -> bool:
    return (
        not s.isdecimal()
        or len(set(s)) == 1
    )
```

This assumes that `s` is a string, as implied by the `int()` call in your original post.  If `s` is already an `int` then you don't need to check whether it's a number and the function would simply be:

```
def rejectSerial(s: int) -> bool:
    return len(set(str(s))) == 1
```

If the type of `s` is completely unknown and you want the function to accept either numbers OR string representations of numbers and simply return True for other input types, then you could just convert it to a string and then apply the string version of this check:

```
def rejectSerial(s) -> bool:
    return (
        not str(s).isdecimal()
        or len(set(str(s))) == 1
    )
```

This will return True if you pass random types like `None` or a list to it, since the string representation of those will fail the `isdecimal()`  check.

If you want the function be be able to accept arbitrary (non-int) values without raising an exception, but only return `False` for int values (not string representations of int values), and you want to enforce the 9-digit positive number requirement, THEN you might want:

```
def rejectSerial(s) -> bool:
    return not (
        isinstance(s, int)
        and 100000000 <= s <= 999999999
        and len(set(str(s))) != 1
    )
```

Comment: int object is not iterable

Comment: Is `s` an `int` or a `str`?

Comment: S could be either. however, in the previous step, i reject ```s``` and return ```True``` if it is not an ```int``` so when we get to checking for all the same digit, we can assume it is an ```int```

Comment: `int(s)` doesn't test if something has a type of `int`, it attempts to convert it.  To test if something is an int you want `isinstance(s, int)`.

Comment: Added yet another suggested implementation.  It's hard to tell exactly what the requirements are so I'm just giving you options.  :P

Answer (score 1):

you can use `set` to achieve this.

```
def rejectSerial(s):
    try:
        int(s)
    except:
        return True
    if len(set(s)) == 1:
        return True

    return False
```

Comment: int object is not iterable

Comment: @Samwise edited his answer to include handling of various types. check that.

Answer (score 0):

@Maxwell: A possible solution could be implemented as in the follows:

```
def rejectSerial(data):
    """Reject data is an integer with different digits.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data: int
        A serial number

    Returns:
    --------
    True if data is not and integer or if it is an integer with the same digits
    False otherwise (this means the data is conforming and must not be rejected)."""
    throw = not isinstance(data, int)   # False is the data is an integer
    datastr = str(data)
    similar = None,
    if len(datastr) == 1: # is the data an integer < 10
        similar = False   # it is a good serial number, and must not be rejected
    else:
        # Create and iterable (here a generator) for testing where the digits are the
        # same
        similar = (datastr[0] == item for item in datastr)
     result = throw or all(similar)
     return result

#------ Test ------
rejectSerial(1)            # -> False
rejectSerial(11111)        # -> True
rejectSerial(11112)        # -> False
```

Answer (score 0):

in C language:

```
int CheckDigits(int givenNumber)
{
    int m = givenNumber; // spare to number to digits
    int count = 0;
    while (m != 0) 
    {
        m = m / 10;
        count++;
    }
    //printf("digit number :%d \n", count);
    
    if(count == 1)
    {
         return 2; // check one digit
    }

    int tempArray[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        tempArray[i] = givenNumber%10;
        givenNumber=givenNumber/10;
        //printf("Digit %d = %d, ",count-i, tempArray[i]);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if(tempArray[0] != tempArray[i])
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```